# Decode Base64 Gzip in python

Tags: python, base64, gunzip, garmin

I'm trying to decode a gzip garmin activity file using Python. According to Garmin the file is a base64 gz file. I'm uploading the file from the browser via post and receiving the data in a Django App.

The beginning of the file looks like this.

> begin-base64 644 data.xml.gz\nH4sIAAAAAAAAA y9a4 lx3Hn d6fguB7JzNuGZkNigNfdrAGbMAYaXeNfbPolXplYiRSIFu

I've used the following code to adjust for padding and decode base64:

```
import base64
padding_factor = (4 - len(data) % 4) % 4
data += "="*padding_factor
data_decoded = base64.b64decode(unicode(data).translate(dict(zip(map(ord, u'-_'), u'+/'))))
```

The beginning of data_decoded looks like this on the screen:

> \xe8"\x9f\xe6\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xeb\x8e\x1dj\xd6\xb1\x9aX3\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03/Z\xe2\w\x1ewz~\x0b\x81\xec\x9c\xcd\xb8fd6(\r}\xda\xc0\x19\xb3\x00a\xa5\xde5\xf6\xcf\xa2U\xe9\x95\x88\x91H\x81n\xcb\xf7\xb4\x9f\xcc\xa7y%\xbd\x95\x9e\x13\xcd\x10\xf9Th\x04\x8d\xdf\xdf\xa6\xba\xa9\xcd\xf9=s\xf8G\xfc

`print data_decoded` looks like this:

> }???a??5?ϢU镈?H?n????̧y%?????Th??ߦ????=s?G?

I then try to unzip the file using the following:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from gzip import GzipFile
sio = StringIO(data_decoded)
gzf = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=sio)
guff = gzf.read()
```

After which I get the following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 245, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 287, in _read
    self._read_gzip_header()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 181, in _read_gzip_header
    raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file'
IOError: Not a gzipped file
```

I also tried saving the file directly to disk and running gunzip from the command line and that also results in the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A gzip file starts with the bytes 0x1f and 0x8b, and the beginning of data_decoded you show doesn't contain that at the beginning. You did something wrong there, because simply doing `'\nH4sIAAAAAAAAA y9a4 lx3Hnd6fguB7JzNuGZkNigNfdrAGbMAYaXeNfbPolXplYiRSIFu'.decode('base64')` gives the two initial bytes needed to describe a gzip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're decoding the entire thing, including the `begin-base64 644 data.xml.gz` part, so you're getting a bunch of garbage at the start:

```
b1 = '''begin-base64 644 data.xml.gz\nH4sIAAAAAAAAA y9a4 lx3Hn
d6fguB7JzNuGZkNigNfdrAGbMAYaXeNfbPolXplYiRSIFu'''

b2 = '''\nH4sIAAAAAAAAA y9a4 lx3Hn
d6fguB7JzNuGZkNigNfdrAGbMAYaXeNfbPolXplYiRSIFu'''
```

If you run your algorithm on b2, you get something starting with this:

```
m\xe8"\x9d\xb6\xac{\xae
```

(I don't know how you lost the `m` in copying and pasting, but either way, it's not valid.)

If you run it on `b2`, you get something starting with this:

```
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00
```

That's what you want.

Of course taking off the `'\n'` has the same effect, since base64 ignores whitespace. So most likely, it's being used as a delimiter. If that's actually a `'\\n'` (aka `r'\n'`) rathern than a `'\n'`, you *have* to remove it to get the right answer.

Also, you seem to be doing a lot of extra work for no good reason. Most likely the data is actually correctly padded, but that part may be worthwhile. But the whole `translate(dict(zip(map(ord, u'-_'), u'+/')))` does the same thing as passing an `altchars` argument to `b64decode`, but less efficiently and harder to read (if it's correct). (By the way, if you were doing `translate` as an optimization against the cost of calling `replace` twice, the conversion to and from Unicode is almost certain to overwhelm the savings. Even if you had profiled and determined that it made a difference, you'd probably want to generate the `translate` map above—both for efficiency, so you don't do it once per string, and, more importantly, for readability.)

Putting it together:

```
data = '''begin-base64 644 data.xml.gz\nH4sIAAAAAAAAA y9a4 lx3Hn
d6fguB7JzNuGZkNigNfdrAGbMAYaXeNfbPolXplYiRSIFu'''
_, data = data.split('\n', 1)
padding_factor = (4 - len(data) % 4) % 4
data += "="*padding_factor
data_decoded = base64.b64decode(data, '-_')
```

Again, if you've got a `'\\n'` rather than a `'\n'`, change the `split` line accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the thorough answer.

Comment: You were right, the padding was unnecessary. Once I split the data I just used base64.b64decode(data, '-_'). Now that I got that right do I still need to run it through StringIO before I unzip?

Comment: @user677325: If you want to do it via `GzipFile`, then yes, `StringIO` is the way to go. The alternative is to parse or skip the header and `zlib.decompress` the body, but you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Ok...sorry to bug you but one more question. What is the start variable in your code?

Comment: @user677325: Sorry, I originally did the `split` explicitly, with a `find` and slicing… but I decided no need to belabor the point, so I took that out… except that I left one line behind. Let me remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip off the beginning of the file since it is not part of the base64 data. If you know that the `\n` will be part of every file you can use it as a delimiter:

```
index = data.find('\\n')
if index > 0:
    data = data[index+2:]
```